# Android JSON - AsyncTask DoInBackground NullPointer

Tags: java, android, json

I'm working on a simple app that will send POST data to a php script, then take the JSON response and put it into a listview. I have the UI things working, and I get a JSON response from the script, but my app crashes and the debug logs show only a `fatal error: main`, pointing towards only my AsyncTask. Is my JSON just not being parsed correctly?

Comment: post the stack trace. also initialize views in `onCreate` and use `runOnUiThread` if you are updating ui from `doInBackground`.

Comment: 1. please move the view initialize code into onCreate(View view) method.

2. Try to test if server return the json correct, you can use postman to do the testing.[postman is a chrome plugin, you can find and install in Chrome web store.]

Comment: Added my stack trace. I'll try your recommendations. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @dsgunter post your adapter code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possibility One

**Step 1** credits @Weibo

Move this to your onCreate, doInBackground cannot do **any** ui stuff. Its the basic rule of AsyncTask. If you must, move the AsyncTask class into your activity where it is needed. Ensure that you dont make it static, since you need the `findViewById` of the onCreate.

```
    final Spinner numPoke = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerNumPokemon);
    final Spinner dexRegion = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerRegion);
    final Spinner pokeType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SpinnerType);
    final ToggleButton incNFE = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleNFE);
    final ToggleButton incLegendary = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleLegendary);
```

**Step 2**

In your onPostExecute, the first statement should have

```
super.doPostExecute(result) ;
```

### Possibility Two

Your `list` or `pokemonList` is **null**, check this out. Use `Toast's` for debugging.

## Advice

From the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), please read the 4 steps.

### The 4 steps

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>    by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>    to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>    parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>    result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>    passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>    publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>    These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>    onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>    undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>    user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>    For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>    a text field.
> 4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>    computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and now I'm getting an onPostExecute-related error.. so at least I'm getting somewhere now!